Filter a pandas data frame to where one column's values are a substring of another column
I have a pandas dataframe where one column only has the first name of someone who started a task, and another has a column of who completed the task:



StartedTask
CompletedTask




Anne
Anne P


Mary
Kirsten S


Bob
Bob N


Cathy
Cathy R


Howard
Molly S



I need to filter this data frame to those who started and completed the task by matching 'Started Task' as a substring of 'Completed Task'. So the data frame I want to return is:



StartedTask
CompletedTask




Anne
Anne P


Bob
Bob N


Cathy
Cathy R



I tried adding a column to the original data frame as a "Match" column I could filter on, which is preferred so I can check the matches before filtering.
df['Match']=str.find(df.StartedTask, df.CompletedTask)
This gave an error: descriptor 'find' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'Series' object
I also tried using the following code to filter the dataset:
filtereddf = df.loc[df['StartedTask'].isin(df['CompletedTask'])]
and this is rendering an empty dataframe (so no matches), which is also incorrect.

You can't use pandas vectorized operations for that, you must loop over the pairs of values (e.g. using zip and a list comprehension):
out = df[[s in c for s, c in zip(df['StartedTask'], df['CompletedTask'])]]

Alternative using numpy.vectorize (note that this won't be faster):
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def paired_isin(a, b):
    return a in b

out = df[paired_isin(df['StartedTask'], df['CompletedTask'])]

Output:
  StartedTask CompletedTask
0        Anne        Anne P
2         Bob         Bob N
3       Cathy       Cathy R


Thank you. Is there any way to specify that the match needs to be beginning from the left of the field, so that I am not matching Anne to Mary Anne?

yes use c.startswith(s)/b.startswith(a) instead of in.

What I ended up doing was similar to what was suggested, but I added in a component of the length of the column because I needed matches to be specific to the first part of the string.
So first I added a column to the data frame that contained the length of the column 'StartedTask', which is necessary because the lengths of the column are of varying values.

df['length']=(lambda x:[len(i) for i in x])(df['StartedTask''])




StartedTask
CompletedTask
Length




Anne
Anne P
4


Mary
Kirsten
4


Bob
Bob N
3


Cathy
Cathy R
5


Howard
Molly S
6



Then I added a column that is the 'CompletedTask' shortened to the length of the 'StartedTask' for each row in the data frame

df['shortened_CompletedTask']=[x[:y] for x, y in zip(df.CompletedTask, df.length)]




StartedTask
CompletedTask
Length
Shortened_CompletedTask




Anne
Anne P
4
Anne


Mary
Kirsten
4
Kirs


Bob
Bob N
3
Bob


Cathy
Cathy R
5
Cathy


Howard
Molly S
6
Molly



And then I used .loc to filter the dataframe to where StartedTask==Shortened_CompletedTask
